# Create a reusable method to build POST call to accept more than 1 headers

Tags: java, rest, post, okhttp

I have a post method to accept 4 parameters.

```
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(type, postData);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(url)
                                    .addHeader("Authorization", ssid)
                                    .post(body)
                                    .build();
```

But few of my calls have more than one header. I can take care of passing the values through a context map. But, how can I build the request in a manner to accept multiple header values.

Example, the above code accepts authorization header.
Another call has two more headers tag1, tag2. the method should be able to tell that 2 sets of values have been passed to it and should build the request accordingly. Is it posssible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to `build` the result immediately. You can store the result of `Request.Builder()` in a variable, loop over your headers, and add them to the builder. This is one of the positives of using a builder instead of a constructor because up until the point that you call `build()`, you can keep modifying what will be built using whatever loops or function you would like to use to modify the builder.

```
public static Request requestWithHeaders(String url, RequestBody body, List<String> headerNames, List<String> headerValues) {
    if (headerNames.size() != headerValues.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
            "Must provide the same number of header names and header values. "
                + "%d header names and %d header values provided",
            headerNames.size(),
            headerValues.size()));
    }

    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body);

    for (int i = 0; i < headerNames.size(); ++i) {
        builder.addHeader(headerNames.get(i), headerValues.get(i));
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

You can then call it like this for instance:

```
Request request = requestWithManyHeaders(
    url,
    body,
    Arrays.asList("auth", "tag1", "tag2"),
    Arrays.asList("authValue", "tag1Value", "tag2Value")
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to constantly modify my method. I want to create a reusable method which will take n number of headers and build the request. In your solution, i have to write a method for every call and add headers manually.

Comment: I adjusted my answer.